# Need flexbox based column with texts to the left and images to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

One response to a similar issue is stack overflow question 44357820. The suggestion there re: not to use percentages with flexbox did not appear to help here. In the left column of the below code I wish to have a number of instances of text to the left of that column with accompanying images to the right, cascading vertically down, and on breakpoint for smartphone I’d like the positioning to be text, then below that, image, then text etc. For starters, I've flex-aligned the image to the right. However, when I emulate a smartphone, it moves off the screen to the left.  Another response that seemed promising is question 28338855, but it doesn’t seem to work in my circumstance.

Any help seriously appreciated!

Thanks!

**CSS + HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/235/?image=1002)
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Column container */
.row {  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}




/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* left column images */
.leftimage
{
    align-self:flex-end;
}


/* Footer */
.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
}


/* Fake image, just for this example */
.fakeimg {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .row, .navbar {   
        flex-direction: column;
    }

}

</style>
</head>
<body>



<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<span>Communication &amp; Learning Center</span><br>
<span style="font-size:.5em;">Expert help in Speech, Language &amp; Literacy since 1984<br><span>
</div>

<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Reading</a>
<a href="#">Language</a>
<a href="#">Speech</a>
</div>

<!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
<div class="row">
<div class="side">
    <div class=leftimage>
    <!-- <img src="sp.png" width=250px> -->

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/235/235/?image=1002">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
    <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    <br>
    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
    <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer">
<h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am running your code now and I see an image on left hand and articles on the right-hand side. Could you please confirm what exact behaviour you want? On mobile you want articles ontop and image below?

Comment: Oh thank you! In the left hand column, the image you see on the right is to be accompanied to its left by text. So, for example, lets say there were 3 images. Img1 Img2 Img3. I'd like them all stacked vertically to the right side of that column. And to the left of each image, also stacked vertically, txt1 txt2 and txt3. And when the screen is on a smartphone, I'd like the stack to be, from top to bottom, txt1, Img1, txt2, Img2, txt3, Img3 etc. Please let me know if this explains it sufficiently. Thank you again! Steve

Comment: PS- the much wider column on the right, with the articles, are not part of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK man, If I understand correctly then Here you go. I have added 3 pictures for test and corresponding text to the left hand side of the image which will be aligned at center. If you don't want centre alignment just remove this `"align-items:center"`. Here is the working example..

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Text 1</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/235/235/?image=1002">
  </div>
</div>
```

Styling

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/235/?image=1002)
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Column container */
.row {  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}




/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* left column images */
.leftimage
{
    align-self:flex-end;
}

.leftimage .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.leftimage .wrapper .text {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
}


/* Fake image, just for this example */
.fakeimg {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .row, .navbar {   
        flex-direction: column;
    }

  .leftimage .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .leftimage .wrapper .text{
     margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hzux2zka/